# Castle.Windsor: IoC resolution of SWF controls without skinned look and feel

Tags: c#, winforms, inversion-of-control, look-and-feel, castle

I am using several services that are registered inside my IoC container. There is an interface IFormService to make forms accessible from within my main application. The interface is defined by

```
public interface IFormService
{
    System.Windows.Forms.Form Form { get; }
}
```

and for example implemented by a class MainFormService which returns the main form instance.

```
container.Register(
    Component.For<IFormService>()
             .ImplementedBy<MainFormService>()
             .Named("Application.Forms.MainForm")
    );
```

After application initialization, I am using this service to retrieve the form and let the application run:

```
Form mainForm = this.ServiceContainer
                    .Resolve<IFormService>("Application.Forms.MainForm")
                    .Form;
Application.Run(mainForm);
```

This works perfectly. The only issue is that the controls on the form look sort of 95-ish:

[image: 95-ish-looking Windows Form]

Later in my development I want to switch to using DevExpress skins which seems to produce the same issue. Why is that happening and how could I solve this properly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Why is that happening and how could I solve this properly?" Why is what happening? That's the expected look of a Windows Form if you haven't styled it.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that. Though in the forms designer the button has the default Win7 theme. But why is the theme information not passed along with the controls by resolving forms via the service?

Comment: Ah, never mind. Looks like I forgot to call Application.EnableVisualStyles() before running with the main form. Thanks for the hint. :)